# Creating MasterMind in Java using Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm  a beginner in Java and am creating an game for a project. I am creating a version of MasterMind using Swing.

This is what I've got so far:

```
package GUI;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class GUIMasterMind implements ActionListener {
JFrame frame;
JPanel contentPane;
JLabel label, prompt, show, blackPegs, whitePegs;
JButton step, newGame;  
JTextField guessBox;
private String[] args;
int guess;

public GUIMasterMind() {

    //frame created
    frame = new JFrame("MasterMind:");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    // content pane
    contentPane = new JPanel();      
    contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 10, 5));
    contentPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));


    prompt = new JLabel("Enter a guess: ");
    contentPane.add(prompt);

    guessBox = new JTextField();
    guessBox.addActionListener(this);
    contentPane.add(guessBox);

    newGame = new JButton("New Game");
    newGame.setActionCommand("New Game");
    newGame.addActionListener(this);
    contentPane.add(newGame);

    step = new JButton("Compare");
    step.setActionCommand("Compare");
    step.addActionListener(this);
    contentPane.add(step);

    show = new JLabel("Results");
    contentPane.add(show);

    blackPegs = new JLabel("Black Pegs: ");
    contentPane.add(blackPegs);

    whitePegs = new JLabel("White Pegs: ");
    contentPane.add(whitePegs);

    frame.setContentPane(contentPane);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);


}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    String eventName = event.getActionCommand();

    String g1 = guessBox.getText();

    if(eventName.equals("New Game")){
        GUIMasterMind.main(args);
    } 
    else if(eventName.equals("Compare")){


        String[] guess = new String[4];

        for (int i = 0; i < guess.length; i++) {
            guess[i] = g1.substring(i, i+1);
            System.out.println(guess[i]);
        }

        MMCode MM = new MMCode(guess);
        show.setText("This was your guess: "+ MM.toHTML());

        if(MM.compareTo() == 1){
            System.out.println("If you would like to start a new game press the button!");
        } 
        else if(MM.compareTo() == 0){
            prompt.setText("Guesses remaining: ");
        } 
        else {
            prompt.setText("Error");
        }
        guessBox.setText("");
        System.out.println("done");
        }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            GUIMasterMind game = new GUIMasterMind();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Currently when my game runs I have the user enter a code and that code is compared to the computer's own generated code. My problem however is in the actionPerformed() method. I want that segment of code to be able to keep rerunning without having to create a altogether new password. I've tried various loops to no success. Any help would be appreciated.

Also you may ignore the white/black peg code, I'll solve that later. I just want my program to run correctly first. Here is my other class. The purpose of this class is to compare the 2 arrays, the guess and the secret.

```
package GUI;


public class MMCode {
String[] guess = new String[4];
String[] secret = new String[4];
int num;

public MMCode(String[] guessess){
    for (int i = 0; i < guess.length; i++) {
        this.guess[i] = guessess[i];
    }

    setSecret();

}

public void setSecret(){
    for (int i = 0; i < secret.length; i++) {
        num = ((int)(Math.random()*6+1));
        secret[i] = Integer.toString(num);
    }
}

public String getSecret(){
    return ("The secret code is: "+secret[0]+secret[1]+secret[2]+secret[3]);
}

public void setGuess(){

}

public String getGuess(){
    return ("Your guess is:      "+guess);
}

public int compareTo(){

    if(guess[0].equals(secret[0]) && guess[1].equals(secret[1]) && guess[2].equals(secret[2]) && guess[3].equals(secret[3])){
        System.out.println("Congratulations you've guessed the computer's code!");
        return 1;
    } else if (!(guess[0].equals(secret[0]) && guess[1].equals(secret[1]) && guess[2].equals(secret[2]) && guess[3].equals(secret[3]))){
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}

public String toHTML(){
    String html = "";


    html += guess[0].toString();
    html += guess[1].toString();
    html += guess[2].toString();
    html += guess[3].toString();
    return html;
}

 }
```

Comment: I don't see any "passwords" in your code--are you talking about `setSecret`?  If `MMCode` represents one set of guesses, and you don't want them to have to enter a "secret" every time they enter a guess, then you don't want the secret stuff to be in `MMCode`.  Move it to a different class.  Having a class that handles two totally unrelated concepts ("guesses" and "passwords") is poor design anyway, and the problems you're having are a very good example of why it's poor.

Answer (score 2):

Start by changing the constructor of the `MMCode` so it doesn't need the guess...

```
public MMCode(){
    setSecret();
}
```

Add a new method called `setGuess`, for example...

```
public void setGuess(String[] guessess){
    for (int i = 0; i < guess.length; i++) {
        this.guess[i] = guessess[i];
    }
}
```

Take `MMCode MM = new MMCode(guess);` from the `actionPeformed` method and make it a instance variable

```
public class GUIMasterMind implements ActionListener {
    //...
    private MMCode mmCode;
    //...
    public GUIMasterMind() {
        //...
        mmCode = new MMCode();
        //...
```

Then in `actionPerformed` method, you simply need to update the instance of `MMCode`...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    //...
    else if(eventName.equals("Compare")){
        String[] guess = new String[4];

        for (int i = 0; i < guess.length; i++) {
            guess[i] = g1.substring(i, i+1);
            System.out.println(guess[i]);
        }

        mmCode.setGuess(guess);
        //...
```

Comment: Hey thanks for responding! I've worked around my problem with a bit of help from your ideas! I'm missing however one component from my program... I'd like to have a counter that decreases based on each time a guess is made. Meaning that the player only has a set amount of guess he/she can make. My current novice attempt looks like this:

Comment: So, in your `actionPerformed`, you need to increment a `counter` value of some kind (which you can then use to update a `JLabel` on the screen).  If the `counter` exceeds the number of allowed guesses, game over...